# How to Print a string from a specific line in a text file based off if my input exists in an alternate text file

Tags: python, string, python-3.4, chatbot

I am making a program that is almost like a chatbot. That being said, there are 3 modes to it: menu mode, teach mode, and chat mode.

In teach mode, it asks for the user to enter some input (ex. what color is the sky?). It then saves the user's input as a string in a text file called "calls".
Then, it asks for one more bit of input which will be the response to the first bit of input we gave (ex. the sky is blue). It gets saved in another text file called "resp" aka responses. All input is stored on its own new line in the text files.

NOW, with that bit of background info, Here is where I am stuck:

While in chat mode, I want the user to be able to type in one of the strings located in "calls.txt" and have the program respond with whatever string is located on the equivalent line # in "resp.txt".

To sort of visualize what I'm trying to get here, I am trying to sell this effect:

[This is the Output I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EsxZ.jpg)

Any Ideas?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: On top of what @mkrieger1 asked, we're probably going to need your code and some test data. See: [mcve].

Comment: I have not yet tried to code the chat mode any farther than making it so that you can enter it.:

Comment: Put your example in your question, not an image.  Indent everything 4 spaces so that it is all treated as if it were code.  (And nothing of what you show has anything to do with IDLE.)  I would advise against imitating the python interactive '>>> ' prompt, as that should mean 'enter Python code'.

Comment: Never use images of text. They are difficult for everyone to read, and impossible for the visually impaired to read. They also can't be indexed or searched. Instead, copy and paste your text directly into the question.

Answer (score -1):

Try saving the questions and answers in two lists, then saving the lists to files. If you put the questions and answers in the same place in both lists/files, you should be able to find one when the other is inputted.

Here is the example code I made (you will need to make the files beforehand):

```
def readfiles():
    global callslst
    global resplst
    #This reads the files and saves them to a variable
    calls = open('calls.txt', 'r')
    resp = open('resp.txt', 'r')
    callslst = calls.readlines()
    resplst = resp.readlines()
    calls.close()
    resp.close()

def writefiles():
    #This opens the files for editing
    calls = open('calls.txt', 'a')
    resp = open('resp.txt', 'a')
    question = input('What is the question? ')
    calls.write(f'\n{question}')
    answer = input('What is the answer? ')
    resp.write(f'\n{answer}')
    calls.close()
    resp.close()

readfiles()

mode = input('Would you like to chat or teach me? ')

if mode.lower() == 'teach':
    writefiles()
    readfiles()

if mode.lower() == 'chat':
    readfiles()
    ask = input('What would you like to ask me? ')
    if ask in callslst:
        pos = callslst.index(ask)
        print(resplst[pos])
    else:
        print("I don't know the answer to that one.")
```